# Hive - No table is listing after successful Sqoop import

Tags: mysql, apache, hadoop, hive, sqoop

After successful import into Hive using **Sqoop**, I can't see the recently imported table in **Hive**.

`import` command

```
./sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/extedu --table user --username TALHA -P --warehouse-dir /home/talha/warehouse --direct
```

**Hive Tables**

```
hive> show tables;
OK
Time taken: 0.038 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with Hive, set following property in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

instead of `metastore-db`, give some absolute path such as

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=**/home/user/hive/metastore_db**;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

Then check. Hopefully it will work

Comment: in the conf folder of Hive, there's no hive-site.xml file. I copied the template file and named it as hive-site.xml. Done what you said and also changed warehouse.dir, still same.  `<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/home/talha/warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>`    `<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/talha/hive/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>`

Comment: The location should be some existing location on your local system

Answer (score 0):

Your command should contain "--hive-import" option.

More on Hive import [here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive).

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `13/03/25 23:52:15 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Failed to start database '/home/talha/hive/metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
13/03/25 23:52:15 INFO hive.HiveImport: NestedThrowables:
13/03/25 23:52:15 INFO hive.HiveImport: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/talha/hive/metastore_db', see the next exception for details.`

Comment: Does this path `/home/talha/hive` exist on your local machine?

Comment: Then there is a possibility that you do not have write permissions to that location. Try reverting `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` property to what it was originally or to some other location where you have permissions.